# Does transactions lock tables or should I lock them in application code?

Tags: mysql, sql, concurrency, transactions

I have 2 tables A and B.
In my application code I update some rows in A and then update table B with let's say the amounts of the rows I processed in table A.
To keep it simple I do the following in my application code:

```
dbh->begin;   
my $amount =  0;   
foreach my $item (@item) {  
   my $row = dbh->do("UPDATE A SET VALUE = ?, STATUS = 'processed' WHERE STATUS <> 'processed' and ID = 12", under, $item->{amount});  
   $amount += $item->{amount} if($row);  
}  
if($amount) {  
   dbh->do("UPDATE B SET AMOUNT = ? WHERE id = ?", undef, $amount, 1234);  
}  
$dbh->commit;
```

I kept it simple (ignore any syntax errors please) to show the idea.
The question is:
What happens when 2 transactions run this code at the same time?
Ideally I would like to be run in serial mode. How can I do that? MySQL uses repeatable read right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do transactions lock tables or should I lock them in application code?

Since you haven't specified which storage engine you're using, I'm going to assume InnoDB. [InnoDB uses *row-level* locking](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-transaction-model.html) inside transactions (and with InnoDB, you're always in a transaction, even when autocommit mode is enabled). You don't have to manually lock InnoDB tables with `LOCK TABLES`; the appropriate rows will be locked automatically when you execute a statement.

> What happens when 2 transactions run this code at the same time?

By transactions, I assume you mean threads or processes. Here is one possible scenario:

1. process1 executes first `UPDATE`, locking row `ID` = 12 in table `A`
2. process2 tries to execute first `UPDATE`, but row `A.ID` = 12 is locked. Wait for lock to be released
3. process1 executes second `UPDATE`, locking row `ID` = 1234 in table `B`
4. process1 commits transaction, releasing both locks
5. process2 obtains lock on row `A.ID` = 12 and runs `UPDATE`. Since the value was already updated by process1, nothing is changed and the second `UPDATE` is skipped
6. process2 commits transaction, releasing lock

Note that it's possible to time out while waiting for a lock. If that happens, the transaction that timed out will be [rolled back](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-deadlock-detection.html).

Comment: Yes InnoDB. The transaction that times out and is aborted, is it restarted?

Comment: You can add logic to your application to retry failed transactions, but the database engine won't do it automatically.

Comment: From textbooks, I have read that transactions failing for reasons *other* than code errors are restarted

Comment: Do you have a specific example? Transactions that were incomplete at the time of a server crash or shutdown are [rolled back automatically](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-recovery.html) (not restarted). Transactions that fail due to a lock timeout are also [rolled back automatically](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-deadlock-detection.html).

Comment: Hm. The book I am consulting (Silberschatz) says this behavior is implementation dependent. May restart or may kill